# Multiqueue RabbitListener using spEL

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm starting with RabbitMQ I created a Spring Boot Project with Maven and I'm using the Spring dependencies to make things work, however, trying out the listeners externalizing the queues names and trying to make it "multiqueue" through the annotation:

```
@RabbitListener(containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory", queues = {"#{'${my.property.containing.the.queues}'.split(',')}"})
```

And as mentioned in the documentation of **spring amqp**

> starting with version 1.5, you can externalize the queue names using
>   property placeholders, and SpEL:
>
> ```
> @Component public class MyService {
>
> @RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${property.with.comma.delimited.queue.names}'.split(',')}" )
>      public void processOrder(String data, @Header(AmqpHeaders.CONSUMER_QUEUE) String queue) {
>          ...
> }
> ```

I just get and error with the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myListenerBean' defined in file [F:\workspace\MyProject\target\classes\co\com\listener\MyListenerClass.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @RabbitListener can't resolve '[Ljava.lang.String;@4d18b73a' as either a String or a Queue
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:690)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:970)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:959)
    at co.com.ExtendedAppConfig.main(ExtendedAppConfig.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @RabbitListener can't resolve '[Ljava.lang.String;@4d18b73a' as either a String or a Queue
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.resolveQueues(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:307)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processAmqpListener(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:242)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:493)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:473)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:205)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

My **pom.xml** is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Organization-RabbitMQ</groupId>
    <artifactId>Extended-Orchestrator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependency to another project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Organization-RabbitMQ</groupId>
            <artifactId>Generic-Orchestrator</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I'm I missing something ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely has been introduced in the `1.5 GA`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-533.

Looks like your `spring-rabbit` dependency is in `1.4.x` version still somehow: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/1.4.x/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L307

Try to provide

```
<spring-amqp.version>1.5.6.RELEASE</spring-amqp.version>
```

property into your pom. Or even better try to understand via `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` who pulls a wrong version for you and fix that conflict.

Comment: You were absolutely rigth, the project still has a reference to **amqp 1.4.6** which is the one managed by an earlier parent release I had in that project.

Comment: OK. Why just don't follow with SO rules and don't accept the answer to close the question and let other people to get a gain during search for similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Queue name in System variable, and need customize the name value with conditionals, you can use Spel:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{'${cluster.name}' != null?'batch.queue-${cluster.name}':'batch.queue'}", containerFactory = "listenerContainerFactory")
```